# Different URL based on same server but different DNS entry

Tags: apache, url, dns

We have a server, say 192.168.1.5, and we have two DNS entries for it:

server.domain.com
ftplogs.domain.com

Both of which point to the server's IP.

I'd want to have server.domain.com redirect to server.domain.com/page1, and I'd like to have ftplogs.domain.com redirect to ftplogs.domain.com/logs.

Any ideas on how to pull this off? Have been fighting with mod_rewrite rules for a bit now.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try it:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName server.domain.com
    RewriteEngine On
    Redirect / http://server.domain.com/page1
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName ftplogs.domain.com
    RewriteEngine On
    Redirect / http://ftplogs.domain.com/logs
</VirtualHost>
```

This work for me :-)

Comment: Have you ever tried this with SSL? I'm sorry, I should have specified the SSL.conf part in my post.

Comment: Weird, with both ports set to *.443 I'm getting the Apache "VirtualHost overlap on port 443, the first has precedence" error.

Comment: put "Listen 443" at first line in the httpd-vhosts.conf

Comment: Sorry didn't answer sooner, this worked, had to fiddle around a bit but it's all good! Thank you so much for your idea!